# Concurrent writes to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have an instance of Neo4j running remotely (it's in an Azure VM)

I have a large amount of data I want to populate the graph with: about 1M nodes, each of which may have ~100 relationships.

If I were to add these from my local machine, I can add around 1000 nodes per hour I.e it will take about a thousand hours to populate the graph.

I could distribute the uploading e.g. running a number of Azure workers to push data into Neo in parallel.

My question is: will Neo be able to handle this? Particularly, a single node may have new relationships to nodes not yet created, and will create them - all create operations using cypher MERGE.

If Neo will be happy with this, great. If not, are there any frameworks / best practices that will help?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but why not directly load the dataset locally, then swap it out on the VM

Comment: As a side note, 1000 nodes per hour seems incredibly slow, even remotely

Comment: Neo4j can ingest up to **a million nodes per second** locally, so there seems to be something really off. Please share *exactly* what you do and how you ingest your data.

Comment: Do you have indexes / constraints for your label/property combinations?

Comment: Yikes I guess OP did say 1,000 nodes **per hour**.  That's remarkably slow.  Unless the nodes themselves have a huge amount of data in them, yeah something's really off about the way they're being ingested in the first place.

Comment: Thanks all - I'm processing documents which contain relationships to other documents (which may not yet exist in the graph) - it's 1000 *documents* per hour, so potentially 100k nodes per hour if 100 relationships exist and the nodes are new.

Comment: **Please share exactly what you do and how you ingest your data. You code, statements raw data examples etc.** Otherwise no one can help you.